# Is there a way to insert data to a user made column in for SQLite?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am working on a Python program that takes in user input and stores the inputs to a database using SQLite. A problem that I run into is that I want to give the option to the user to make a new column in the table, but I don't know how to insert/edit/delete/search data to the new column. Is there a good way to do this in Python? My first idea is to make a list of all the column names and make a separate list to check which columns the user wants to insert/search to and do the query from there, but that does not seem to be a good idea to me because it makes the user experience not good since it basically asks the user what to input every time the user wants to input something. Please help. Thank you.

Edit: This is an example scenario:
Say, a table has 4 columns: name, address, date of birth, and job. There are functions that ask for user input for those columns and store it to the database. Then, the user adds another column, say phone number. How can you insert/search data to/from the phone number column?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Say, a table has 4 columns: name, address, date of birth, and job. There are functions that ask for user input for those columns and store it to the database. Then, the user adds another column, say phone number. How can you insert into the phone number column? @tit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new column to your table using :

```
ALTER TABLE useTable ADD COLUMN phone TEXT DEFAULT '-'; 
-- Insert Data
INSERT INTO userTable (name,address,dateBirth, phone)
VALUES(searchedName,searchedAddress,searcheDateBirth, searchedPhone);
-- Search for Data, eg phone
SELECT * from userTable where name like '%Sky%'
```

[see doc for restictions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. What I am wondering is how to insert/search data from the new column that was created by the user. Is such action even possible?

Comment: It does help. Thank you.